# Get name of top-level menu - Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have some menu-items published on footer of my site.

```
-FAQ
-Contact Us
```

These are actually menu-items and their main menu name is `Information`

I want to show their main-menu name as well like so:

```
Information
  -FAQ
  -Contact Us
```

I have this code

```
    $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
    $parent_title = $menu->getItem(2)->title;
```

The main menu named `Information` has id `2` but it does not show anything :(

So how do I get that menu name?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this way:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$parent = $menu->getItem($active->parent_id);
var_dump(parent);
```

and tell us what you get : )

if this don't work for you, change line with parent to:

```
$parent = $menu->getItems('id', $active->parent_id);
```

regards